# Does SQL Server Compact Edition 4 finally support Views?

Tags: features

Just read about the [release of SQL Server CE 4](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/13/announcing-release-of-asp-net-mvc-3-iis-express-sql-ce-4-web-farm-framework-orchard-webmatrix.aspx) and then searched all through their [product website](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx), I still cannot find a feature overview.

Previous versions of SQL Server CE didn't support views, I was hoping that they removed the limitations.

**My question is:**

Is there a page which lists the features and limitations of SQL Server CE 4?

*(Edit: I found this [feature comparison for 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), but not for 4.0)*

Comment: I think the straight answer is "the documentation just isn't up yet"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed WebMatrix w/ CE 4.0 last night.  I can't confirm for sure that CE 4.0 can't do views, but I can tell you that there's no support for creating them in WebMatrix.

Comment: I'm also not able to create views on a CE database using VS2010.

Answer (score 3):

The closest I can find to an answer from MS... at least one of their moderators: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/8b18e08b-c345-4f6d-98fd-2273c933ea2b

Comment: Thank you! Too bad, at least Views would have enabled my to migrate old MDB Access projects to SQL CE...

Comment: @Uwe - If you need portable database, SQLite supports views

Answer (score 2):

There is now a list of features from MS, for Sql Server CE 4.0:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140.aspx

Views are unfortunately not supported